# No muestras imagenes laravel en produccion

Tags: php, laravel, host

he mirado y comprobado soluciones y ninguna de ellas me ha servido, el caso es que en localhost me funciona perfecto el proyecto, pero en produccion no me cargan las imagenes, lo curioso es que todo el proceso lo realiza bien, cuando creo un artículo añado la imagen, la url queda en la base de datos la imagen sube a storage/app/public/posts y despues se ve reflejado en el acceso directo de public/storage/public/posts ,pero no me muestra las imagenes cuando llamo al campo url de la base de datos(dentro de la etiqueta para mostrar imagenes).
Mi sospecha es que uso un htacces con reglas para apuntar al index de la carpeta public , no se si me falta algo ahí para hacer referencia a las imagenes, he revisado los permisos, el propietario de las carpetas, tengo el acceso directo de storage funcionando bien.
Lo menciono: he usado el metodo storage-link en local y he creado un acceso directo en produccion desde la terminal que trabaja bien.

Quizas alguien se le ocurra donde puedo investigar, es mi primer proyecto en laravel.

Les paso el código de htacces donde están las reglas para apuntar al index en la carpeta public.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

</IfModule>
```

Les paso el metodo del controlador donde ejecuta la acion de guardar la imagen:

```
public function GuardarArticulo(StorePostRequest $request, Post $post)
                             {
                             $post = new Post();
                             $post->name = $request->name;
                             $post->extract = $request->extract;
                             $post->body = $request->body;
                             $post->status = $request->status;
                             $post->slug = $request->slug;
                             $post->user_id = auth()->id();
                             $post->category_id = $request->category_id;

                             if($request->file('url')){
                             // Storage se encarga de guardar la imagen en la carpeta tmp, y con put la llevamos a la carpeta donde se almacenan
                             $url = Storage::put('posts', $request->file('url'));
                             // añadimos la URL en el campo de la tabla
                             $post->url = $url;
                             } else {

                             $post->url = "../storage/posts/indice.png";
                             }

                             
                             $post->save();

                            //  debemos ejecutar el save antes del condicional , si no no existe el ID del post
                            // para generarlo en la tabla muchos a muchos

                            if($request->tags){
                            $post->tags()->attach($request->tags);
                            }
                            $post->save();
                        
                            return redirect()->route('mostrar.articulo', $post->slug);
                 
                         }


                             if($request->file('url')){
                             // Storage se encarga de guardar la imagen en la carpeta tmp, y con put la llevamos a la carpeta donde se almacenan
                             $url = Storage::put('posts', $request->file('url'));
                             // añadimos la URL en el campo de la tabla
                             $post->url = $url;
                             } else {

                             $post->url = "../storage/posts/indice.png";
                             }

                             
                             $post->save();

                            //  debemos ejecutar el save antes del condicional , si no no existe el ID del post
                            // para generarlo en la tabla muchos a muchos

                            if($request->tags){
                            $post->tags()->attach($request->tags);
                            }
                            $post->save();
                        
                            return redirect()->route('mostrar.articulo', $post->slug);
                 
                         }
```

Comment: porque guardas un url en la bd que indique storage?, yo lo que hago es guardar el nombre de la carpeta y el archivo según la logica para saber a que carpeta ingresar, pero solo hasta alli, nombre_Carpeta/nombre_archivo.extension ya que cuando buscas con laravel un archivo comun, el principalmente tratara de buscar en la carpeta public

Comment: Ademas indicas que primero se guarda en ```storage/app/public/posts```, luego indicas que se ve reflejado en un acceso directo (¿Cúal acceso directo?)con la url ```public/storage/public/posts```, luego veo en el codigo no ingresas ningun dato parecido ```$post->url = "../storage/posts/indice.png";```, estas seguro donde estas guardando las cosas?

Comment: en principio si guardo desde la ruta storage es porque pensaba que se hacia así ya que es una imagen fija que es la que se usa si no se selecciona ninguna imagen,  y como me funciona en local pues no he visto que este mal, el acceso directo lo crea el metodo storage-link en la carpeta public donde se encuentra el index.

Comment: Bueno,si sé donde se guardan las cosas por que las veo al crear el articulo y veo tambien el cambio en la base de datos y como se sube el archivo a la carpeta storage/app/public/posts , normalnete si seleccionas una imagen y la subes, se queda de la manera siguiente guarda en la base de datos: posts/tiVKc6weM8Z900er6N0VDNjWR50ADVflbFhqnGCd.jpg y este mismo nombre se ve reflejado en ambas carpetas, pero no me muestra la imagen

Comment: No conosco muchos esos metodos, normalmente uso lo que te comente, ahora haz lo siguiente, presiona f12 y ve que dirección de url te esta mandando las imagenes

Comment: @ernestojimenez físicamente los archivos van a `storage/bla bla bla /` y dentro de `public ` hay un symlink.  Al OP: revisa el document root que figura en tu virtualhost de apache. Es posible que ya esté apuntando a public, por lo que la reescritura es redundante. Dependiendo lo que figure ahí, tu htaccess puede ser del todo innecesario

Comment: si quito las reglas del htacces no me funciona la web, debido a que la carpeta donde debe estar el index en el host se llama "public_html" y yo he subido el proyecto a esa carpeta, pero claro  el index del proyecto se encuentra en  public_htm/public y para que funcione he usado esas reglas dentro de htacces. Por cierto soy novato y es mi primer proyecto he llegado hasta aquí solo, no me juzgen :)

Answer (score 1):

Bueno he podido encontrar la ruta y ha quedado de esta manera el codigo:

```
   if($request->file('url')){
                             // Storage se encarga de guardar la imagen en la carpeta tmp, y con put la llevamos a la carpeta donde se almacenan
                             $url = Storage::put('posts', $request->file('url'));
                             // añadimos la URL en el campo de la tabla
                             $post->url = 'app/public/'.$url;
                             } else {

                             $post->url = "app/public/posts/indice.png";
                             }
```

En la ruta de la base de datos ha tenido que quedar así para que muestre las imagenes: app/public/storage/posts/indice.png